# Schema file name is not detecting the namespace

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, schema

I'm having the lot of XSD, which is included with single XSD file and all the files are getting valid well and the corresponding XML file also getting valid against corresponding XSD using oxygen XML editor. But while uploading the xml file against the XSD's file in the product. I'm getting the below error:

> Error resolving component 'Definition.attrib'. It was detected that
>   'Definition.attrib' has no namespace, but components with no target
>   namespace are not referenceable from schema document

When I opened the corresponding file, it shows validated in oxygen XML editor. Here is the code for the corresponding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
 >

<xs:include schemaLocation="common-attrib.xsd"></xs:include>
<xs:include schemaLocation="../common/common-attribs.xsd"></xs:include>

<xs:attributeGroup name="mean.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>


<xs:complexType name="mean.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="mean.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="mean" type="mean.type"/>

<xs:attributeGroup name="sdev.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="sdev.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="sdev.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="sdev" type="sdev.type"/>

<!-- "variance" -->

<xs:attributeGroup name="variance.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="variance.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="variance.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="variance" type="variance.type"/>

<!-- "median" -->

<xs:attributeGroup name="median.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="median.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="median.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="median" type="median.type"/>

<!-- "mode" -->

<xs:attributeGroup name="mode.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="mode.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="mode.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="mode" type="mode.type"/>

<!-- "moment" -->

<xs:attributeGroup name="moment.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:complexType name="moment.type">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="moment.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="moment" type="moment.type"/>

<!-- "momentabout" -->

<xs:attributeGroup name="momentabout.attlist">
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Definition.attrib"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="Common.attrib"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:group name="momentabout.content">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="Content-statistics.class"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="momentabout.type">
  <xs:group ref="momentabout.content"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xs:attributeGroup ref="momentabout.attlist"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="momentabout" type="momentabout.type"/>

<!-- And the group of everything -->

<xs:group name="Content-statistics.class">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="mean"/>
    <xs:element ref="sdev"/>
    <xs:element ref="variance"/>
    <xs:element ref="median"/>
    <xs:element ref="mode"/>
    <xs:element ref="moment"/>
    <xs:element ref="momentabout"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:group>


</xs:schema>
```

corresponding xml file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns:CORE="http://www.reallysi.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="oup.xsd">
<documentinfo publisher="OUPAustralia" title="Test Title - HE" titlenumber="1" isbn13="9780190311360" edition="4" author="Reynolds"/>
<chapter no="2">
<title><num>2</num><head>Inquiry Pedagogy</head></title>
<intro>
<para fo="Y"><txt><b>Good pedagogy</b></txt></para>
<para><txt><b>Research</b></txt></para>
</intro>
</document>
```

Can anybody help me on this, why this error is occuring. Please provide me suggestion for this.

Comment: Please also post the XML you are trying to validate. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @potame. I have edited in my question. Please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't made it clear whether a schema document defining `Definition.attrib` is reachable from the top-level schema document or not. There seem to be two possibilities: either (a) there is no declaration of this attribute group, or (b) there is a declaration, but it is in the wrong namespace. Either way, you have a dangling reference.

I suspect the reason you are seeing different effects in different environments is that the XSD specification gives some flexibility to processors when there are dangling references like this. The spec encourages processor to carry on regardless so long as the reference is to a component that is not actually needed for validating this instance document. But the rules are somewhat fuzzy.